# java.sql.SQLException: Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update input_workshop_tasks iw 
set iw.priority_condition1_time = (select iw2.priority_condition1_time 
                                   from input_workshop_tasks iw2 
                                   where iw2.task_id=7 
                                     and iw2.workshop_id =1892) 
where iw.task_id=12 
  and iw.workshop_id =1892
```

Produced Error:
Table name specified twice both as a target for update and separate source for data.

How can I fix this as in other similar question, the setting of the attribute was not done using the same table?

Answer (score 0):

```
update input_workshop_tasks iw, 
       input_workshop_tasks iw2
set iw.priority_condition1_time = iw2.priority_condition1_time 
where iw.task_id = 12 
  and iw.workshop_id = 1892 
  and iw2.task_id = 7 
  and iw2.workshop_id = 1892
```